# CSS Selector - not reaching my element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to get up to speed with CSS. I have a button style that I need to repeat throughout quite a few pages. I've created a class called `bigbutton` that I am using in the following html file. I also use this same class in other html pages.

You'll also see my css file where I define the appearance of this button. The problem that I am having is that when I define the css file as `.bigbutton` these settings have no effect. If I define the css file with `#big_button_container .bigbutton` then everything works perfectly. Unfortunately, I can't do it this way because in other html files, this class won't necessarily be wrapped in this `big_button_container` div.

So, my question is how do I write the css selector such that it will have the desired effect on this bigbutton class? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/mystyles.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/bigbuttons.css" media="screen" />

                <style media="screen" type="text/css">
                    #big_button_container{
                        margin-left:85px;
                        width:809px;
                        padding:14px;
                    }
                </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="frame">
        <div id="page">
            <img id="mainpic" src="images/banner.png" height="390" width="982">

            <div id="big_button_container">        
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <form action="coaches.html">
                                <input type="submit" value="COACHES" class="bigbutton"> 
                            </form>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                                <input type="button" value="GROUPS" class="bigbutton" onclick="()"</td>
                        <td><input type="button" value="WORKOUTS" class="bigbutton" onclick="()"</td>
                        <td><input type="button" value="ATHLETES" class="bigbutton" onclick="()"</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="button" value="PACE GROUPS" class="bigbutton" onclick="()"</td>
                        <td><input type="button" value="USER TYPES" class="bigbutton" onclick="()"</td>
                        <td><input type="button" value="WORKOUT TYPES" class="bigbutton" onclick="()"</td> 
                    </tr>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

css

```
//#big_button_container .bigbutton{    <--this works, but only for this html file
.bigbutton{
    clear:both;
    margin-right:3px;
    margin-top:3px;
    border-style:none; 
    width:200px;
    height:125px;
    background:#c1d72e;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    color:#444444;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: Seems to be css merge issue.. Try `input.bigbutton`. I think this will work.

Comment: Probably some specificity order mixup taking place. Will the "big buttons" always be `input`?

Comment: input.bigbutton was one of the (many) things that I tried. It still isn't getting to the button.  I think that the buttons will always be input, but not entirely sure. I'm willing to go with that assumption for the time being, though. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: Could be related to your HTML being invalid. Just one example, `<input type="button" value="GROUPS" class="bigbutton" onclick="()"</td>`. You failed to close the input tag.

Comment: Please show all rules related to matched input from both CSS files. The issue could be cause, for example, if you have more specific rule matching your input.bigbutton.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it to work. I changed this line:

```
<div id="big_button_container">
```

to

```
<div class="big_button_container">
```

and then moved the css for this container into this same 'bigbuttons.css' file. So, now my css file looks like this:

```
body{
font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
}
p, h1, form, button{border:0; margin:0; padding:0;}

.big_button_container{
    margin-left:85px;
    width:809px;
    padding:14px;
}

.bigbutton{
    clear:both;
    margin-right:3px;
    margin-top:3px;
    border-style:none; 
    width:200px;
    height:125px;
    background:#c1d72e;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    color:#444444;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

I had tried previously to make big_button_container a class, so I really don't know why this works. But it works not only in this file, but also in other html files that use this same button styling. I never like resolving things like this by happenstance, but at least it's solved. If anyone can tell me why this works when it didn't previously, I'd love to hear it.

Thanks to everyone, and sorry to have bothered you. I appreciate your help!